# Why does SwiftUI's ForEach not update when the given data conforms to Equatable?

Tags: swiftui, observedobject, equatable, swiftui-foreach

I'm following the I am following the CS193P Stanford class to learn SwiftUI after working with Storyboards for more than 3 years.

Already having a bit of experience I allowed myself to do things quickly and not exactly like the professor does. This lead me to discovering a behaviour that I can't understand.

Consider the following code:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: EmojiMemoryGame
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 80))]) {
                ForEach(viewModel.cards) { card in
                    CardView(card: card)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            viewModel.choose(card)
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where a Card is defined like this:

```swift
struct Card: Identifiable, Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: MemoryGame<CardContent>.Card, rhs: MemoryGame<CardContent>.Card) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
        
    var isFaceUp = true
    var isMatched = false
    var content: CardContent
    
    var id = UUID()
}

mutating func choose(_ card: Card) {
    guard let index = cards.firstIndex(where: { $0 == card }) else { return }
    cards[index].isFaceUp.toggle()
}
```

Why doesn't the view update when the `viewModel.cards` array is updated?
If I remove only the Equatable protocol, leaving the rest of the app untouched:

```swift
struct Card: Identifiable { //..
```

it works just fine.

Comment: if you put a breakpoint in your `==` implementation, does it get hit?

Comment: Yes it does, when conforming to Equatable it hits for every single card, every time with `lhs == rhs` returning true. ForEach must have some special behaviour when handling Equatables but I can't find how or why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the id never changes (you are initializing it with a UUID) and your == func is only looking at the id of each card to determine equality, the ForEach will never see any change in the other attributes. I had to write the == func as below, and it worked for me.

```
static func == (lhs: MemoryGame.Card, rhs: MemoryGame.Card) -> Bool {
   return lhs.isFaceUp == rhs.isFaceUp &&
   lhs.isMatched == rhs.isMatched &&
   lhs.content == rhs.content &&
   lhs.id == rhs.id
}
```

Comment: So Equatable takes precedence over Identifiable ? This looks really weird to me. It seems perfectly normal that the `id` doesn't change, that is its purpose after all. Imagine if my card struct had 10+ properties, would I need to check every single one of them in the `func == ()`?
How come that ForEach with Identifiable works since the id is the only thing looked and it never changes ?

Comment: I think the issue is that by defining Equatable, you are effectively "overriding" what it means for structures to be equal. By default, Swift considers structs to be equal if and only if all properties of the struct are the same value.

If your card struct had 10+ properties, you would need to determine which of those properties were really needed to define what it means for the cards to be equal. For example, you may decide that the only relevant parts of a card to be considered equal is the content. In that case you could define == as `lhs.content == rhs.content`.

Comment: I think that @jdelano is exactly right. `ForEach()` just uses the IDs to distinguish between elements in the collection, but in order for it to know that there are _changes_ (and thus cause the whole `View` to be redrawn), the `==` needs to check all of the significant properties for changes.